# SQL Filter condition with value or Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

In the below procedure i may pass `@Type` value only sometimes otherwise it will be NULL.

How can i handle querying all data when NULL is passed and specific records when i pass a type. I don't want to build dynamic query for this simple handling.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPatientImages]  
(      
@TenantId BIGINT,       
@PatientId BIGINT,
@Type NVARCHAR(100)        
)      

AS       

BEGIN       
     SET NOCOUNT ON         
IF @TenantId IS NULL       
      RAISERROR('The value for @TenantID should not be null', 15, 1) -- with log      

ELSE      
BEGIN      

SELECT  

P.[DisplayFileName],  
P.[StoredFileName],
P.[Location],
P.[Type],
P.[Description]

FROM  

 PatientImage P

 WHERE P.PatientId=@PatientId AND P.TenantId=@TenantId AND P.[Type]=@Type
 ORDER BY P.[Type] DESC
END  
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE P.PatientId=@PatientId AND P.TenantId=@TenantId AND
      (@Type is null or P.[Type]=@Type)
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try it